# how to pass parameters to intent using bindService?

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to pass parameters (like a double value) to service using activity.bindService,

```
var  intent = Intent(activity, MyService::class.java)
activity.bindService(intent, mServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE)

private val mServiceConnection = object : ServiceConnection {
    override fun onServiceConnected(name: ComponentName, service: IBinder) {
        mBound = true
        val binder = service as MyService.LocalBinder
        mService = binder.service
    }

    override fun onServiceDisconnected(name: ComponentName) {
        mService = null
    }
}
```

I tried using intent.putExtra, but while getting value using getExtra is always null.
I know putExtra is working in startActivity, but it's not working in bindService.

It could be a silly question, but I am not from Android background.

Comment: add your code you putExtra?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
val intent = Intent(activity, MyService::class.java).apply {
    putExtra("your_key", 1.1) // put your value here
}
activity.bindService(intent, mServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE)
```

```
override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder? {
    val value = intent.getDoubleExtra("your_key", 0.0) // 1.1
    return binder
}
```